# Caesar Cipher in python

Tags: python, input, python-2.x

The error which i am getting is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "imp.py", line 52, in <module>
    mode = getMode()
  File "imp.py", line 8, in getMode
    mode = input().lower()
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'encrypt' is not defined
```

Below is the code.

```
# Caesar Cipher


MAX_KEY_SIZE = 26

def getMode():
    while True:
        print('Do you wish to encrypt or decrypt a message?')
        mode = input().lower()
        if mode in 'encrypt e decrypt d'.split():
            return mode
        else:
            print('Enter either "encrypt" or "e" or "decrypt" or "d".')

def getMessage():
    print('Enter your message:')
    return input()

def getKey():
    key = 0
    while True:
        print('Enter the key number (1-%s)' % (MAX_KEY_SIZE))
        key = int(input())
        if (key >= 1 and key <= MAX_KEY_SIZE):
            return key

def getTranslatedMessage(mode, message, key):
    if mode[0] == 'd':
        key = -key
    translated = ''

    for symbol in message:
        if symbol.isalpha():
            num = ord(symbol)
            num += key

            if symbol.isupper():
                if num > ord('Z'):
                    num -= 26
                elif num < ord('A'):
                    num += 26
            elif symbol.islower():
                if num > ord('z'):
                    num -= 26
                elif num < ord('a'):
                    num += 26

            translated += chr(num)
        else:
            translated += symbol
    return translated

mode = getMode()
message = getMessage()
key = getKey()

print('Your translated text is:')
print(getTranslatedMessage(mode, message, key))
```

Comment: This is not related to the error you're seeing, but you might want to have a look at `string.translate()` http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate

Answer (score 7):

The problem is here:

```
print('Do you wish to encrypt or decrypt a message?')
mode = input().lower()
```

In Python 2.x input use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`.

Python 2.x:

- Read a string from standard input: `raw_input()`
- Read a string from standard input and then evaluate it: `input()`.

Python 3.x:

- Read a string from standard input: `input()`
- Read a string from standard input and then evaluate it: `eval(input())`.

Answer (score 2):

`input()` *evaluates* the expression you type. Use `raw_input()` instead.