# How to deal with IndentationError?

Tags: python, syntax, indentation

I get the following error:

```
File "imp.py", line 55
    key = get Key()
      ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

With the following Code:

```
# Caesar Cipher

MAX_KEY_SIZE = 26

def getMode():
    while True:
        print('Do you wish to encrypt or decrypt or brute force a message?')
        mode = raw_input().lower()
        if mode in 'encrypt e decrypt d brute b'.split():
            return mode
        else:
            print('Enter either "encrypt" or "e" or "decrypt" or "d" or "brute" or "b".')

def getMessage():
    print('Enter your message:')
    return raw_input()

def getKey():
    key = 0
    while True:
        print('Enter the key number (1-%s)' % (MAX_KEY_SIZE))
        key = int(raw_input())
        if (key >= 1 and key <= MAX_KEY_SIZE):
            return key

def getTranslatedMessage(mode, message, key):
    if mode[0] == 'd':
        key = -key
    translated = ''

    for symbol in message:
        if symbol.isalpha():
            num = ord(symbol)
            num += key

            if symbol.isupper():
                if num > ord('Z'):
                    num -= 26
                elif num < ord('A'):
                    num += 26
            elif symbol.islower():
                if num > ord('z'):
                    num -= 26
                elif num < ord('a'):
                    num += 26

            translated += chr(num)
        else:
            translated += symbol
    return translated

mode = getMode()
message = getMessage()
if mode[0] != 'b':
key = getKey()
print('Your translated text is:')
if mode[0] != 'b':
print(getTranslatedMessage(mode, message, key))
else: 
    for key in range(1, MAX_KEY_SIZE + 1): 
        print(key, getTranslatedMessage('decrypt', message, key))
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: -1 this "question" can be answered by anyone with a little bit of reading the error message and looking at the code.

Comment: In dat case...why dont u help me

Comment: Please stay well away from cryptography if this kind of error confuses you.

Comment: Are you posting a new question every time you get an error?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883074/caesar-cipher-in-python-please-help-me-where-am-i-going-wrong

Comment: could u pls tell me the changes dat can be made...

Comment: What line number does it say the error was on? The error says something about indentation, so what do you notice about the indentation on that line?

Comment: the title has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: Is he creating a new user account every time he makes a new error? Is everyone in his class cheating from the same source?

Comment: @Gary: these are not proper user accounts, they both are "unregistered user".

Comment: @Silent Your complaint is perfectly valid, and your suggestion that we use proper English around here correct. But please be gentler in phrasing it. Not only for the off chance that *this* poster might, eventually have something to contribute, but because we want an inviting atmosphere.

Answer (score 3):

1. **Do not use `+=` to build strings.**  Use `''.join(mylist)`
2. Do as it asks: give it an indented block.

Answer (score 2):

From [An Informal Introduction to Python](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html), "The body of the loop is indented: indentation is Python’s way of grouping statements."

If you are familiar with C or Java, you might recognize this syntax:

```
if (...)
{
    //do something
}
```

Python does this w/ indentations:

```
if ...
    #do something
```

That said, the rest of your code seems to understand this point.  That you were unable to recognize this when the error occurred means either you got very lucky or you're using someone else's code.

I hope, for your sake, that this isn't a homework assignment, because most universities take a very dim view of plagiarism.

Comment: this seems like a pretty silly problem for an undergrad even

Comment: I can easily see this in an intro to programming class.

Comment: His prof should wave him off from entering this career.  Regrettably software development requires some self-teaching.  Software test on the other hand...